# how to get random documents from MongoDB using prisma ORM

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

Techstack:Next.js 14, MongoDB, Prisma ORM. I have a many documents in my DB but I need random 15 documents each time I request...

If I have to do the same thing using mongoose I can do this:

```
 const selectedProjects = await Project.aggregate([
  { $sample: { size: 15 } },
 ]).exec();
```

How can I accomplish the same in Prisma ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Random results are not currently supported by Prisma. There's an [open feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5894) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to make a function which shuffles the array and gives back

```
function shuffleProjects(projects: Project[]): Project[] {
    // Deep copy the original array to avoid mutating the original array
    const shuffledProjects = [...projects];

    // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
    for (let i = shuffledProjects.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [shuffledProjects[i], shuffledProjects[j]] = [shuffledProjects[j], shuffledProjects[i]];
    }

    return shuffledProjects;
}
```

Then called

```
 const shuffledProjects = shuffleProjects(projects);
```